# Confused about stock merger reflection on portfolio

Tags: stocks, investing, trading, financial-literacy, stock-markets

So I have stock in [**ASX**](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASX?p=ASX) who announced a merger earlier in the year with [**SPIL**](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPIL?p=SPIL) and I received all the usual merger notices etc about they will become "ASE Industrial Holding" and the way the share exchange will reflect etc.

However, I'm confused about a couple things since this is the first stock I own that's gone through a merger and was hoping someone could lend some experience to an amateur.

Whereas currently [**ASX**](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ASX?p=ASX) reflects the name change now where I check it, however [**SPIL**](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPIL?p=SPIL) remains the same, and they both appear to be still separate entities. In my position dashboard on TD no gains are reflected, the symbols remains the same, the amount of shares remains the same, and what I would expect the new valuation isn't reflected?

Is this just because of a timing thing as they go through the motions and eventually TD will catch up and the change(s) will get reflected, or am I just missing something as an amateur investor? What if something came up and I wanted to sell those shares for some liquid cash to put elsewhere, are they locked while merger is in motion?

I do apologize as I've read lots of amateur resources going through the scenario but they don't seem to apply in this one. Looking for a little more direct education from another pair of eyes. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however SPIL remains the same, and they both appear to be still separate entities

Yahoo is showing a snapshot of the SPIL. If you see the date below the price of the quote;

> 8.59+0.01 (+0.12%) At close: **April 17** 4:00PM EDT

is 17th April on which this share was de-listed.

> Whereas currently ASX reflects the name change now where I check it,

Yes this is the new entity. Your shares have now got converted into ASE Industrial Holding Co. [See how the entities got merged](http://focustaiwan.tw/news/aeco/201802120017.aspx). Essentially ASE and SPIL created holding company ASE Holding. All shares of ASE and SPIL are owned by ASE Holding. And ASE Holding is traded on exchange.

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't even notice the past date, cheers!

Comment: @ChrisW. Ya, it's kind of non intuitive. They should do more to highlight defunct/delisted stocks